# trying to calculate a GST field containing materials and labour that doesnt seem to work with no material content

Tags: ms-access

I have Quotation form that has a calculated field that is for GST and is derived from labour and material totals on the same form. The calculation for GST works fine if there is data in both labour and materials fields but doesnt  if there is nothing in the materials field as some of jobs do not require material.

﻿﻿GST   =IIf(IsError(([txtLabourTotal]+[txtMaterialsTotal])*0.1),0,([txtLabourTotal]+[txtMaterialsTotal])*0.1)

The Expected calculation is to have the GST show an amount if there is no materials to calculate for. I have tried a number of ways to overcome this problem that all had the same result. Is there a way that I can overcome this?

Comment: Learn to [debug](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) or [debug2](https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/debugging.html) to check the values of`{txtLabourTotal]` and `[txtMaterialsTotal]` and check result of`?(Null + 2) * 3`in immediate window. Then follow Andres answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `IsError()`, because NULL values are no error.

Use `Nz()` to map NULL values to zero:

```
=(Nz([txtLabourTotal], 0) + Nz([txtMaterialsTotal], 0)) * 0.1
```

should do it.

Comment: I prefer Nz too, but OP just needs to change`IsError`to`isNull`to solve the questiom, what is a VBA function, in opposite to Nz, that is an ACCESS function (only availible in`Ms Access or with reference)`. Maybe add that to answer.

Comment: `IsNull` still requires the `IIf` and duplication of the expression, which is bad.  IMHO using `Nz` is cleaner. @ComputerVersteher

Comment: I totally agree, but it is not vba universal (and there are far more Excel users).